# Firestore 19 React never saving in the cache

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The problem:
I have a set of data that are never meant to change (maybe once every month or two) which I need to get on every refresh.
I have a couple of techniques to handle it but I wanted to try caching first.
I found that I need to try to get from the cache first if it's found move on else get from the server which suits my case.

**if you recommend a better way please let me know**

```
let queryDocs = await getDocsFromCache(query);
      if(queryDocs.empty){
        queryDocs.log('cache empty')
        queryDocs = await getDocsFromServer(query)
      }
```

I always get cache empty even if I check metdata.fromCache it will be always false;
This is my initialize app in firebase.js

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig,{
  localCache: persistentLocalCache(/*settings*/{
    tabManager: persistentMultipleTabManager()
  }),
  cacheSizeBytes: CACHE_SIZE_UNLIMITED
})
```

Comment: I am not sure what the question is and it's always a good idea to indicate your coding platform as well as with Firebase product you're using (Firestore, Realtime Database etc). Big picture is that Firestore offers [offline persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) so why not use it? Firebase will always look to local data first before retrieving from the server so if your data is fairly static, that's a big cost savings.

Comment: @Jay Hey jay I already added the tag firebase but you are right I should've made it more clear in the title which I did now for my issue I already followed the link you shared but it is never reading from the cache nor creating a cache for my data and I placed the code that the documentation suggests for some data yes they are fairly static which is why I want to use offline persistence

Comment: Great! Much better. But now you know offline is available so I think perhaps either changing this question to reflect your updated code and attempt  - or - possibly creating a new question that includes your new code and what you've attempted may be a good idea.